# How can I configure a frontend or backend instance in Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have created a function in App Engine which uses the Sheets service to read some data, process it and then Post it to another place. I run it with a cron job each half an hour.

The documentation says it offers 28 free hours to "Frontend Instances (Automatic Scaling Modules)" and 9 free hours to "Backend Instances (Basic and Manual Scaling Modules)"

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas#Instances

My app is being catalogued as a "backend" and consuming more than the free 9 hours available to backends.

**- How do I specify my instance as a Backend or as a Frontend?**

---> Maybe with the scaling specification?

---> Docs say this: "Note that when you use the Modules API, the module's instance class determines which quota applies." But I don't understand this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quote you gave from the documentation gives you the answer

> "Frontend Instances (Automatic Scaling Modules)" and 9 free hours to "Backend Instances (Basic and Manual Scaling Modules)"

In your `appengine-web.xml` or `app.yaml` you will be specifying the scaling type. By default it is automatic (which means 'frontend' instances in old terminology), but if you specify *basic* or *manual* it will be classed as a 'backend' instance.

Comment: Hi, thanks. Do you know why does it say that the Modules API determines which quota applies?